# How to create Custom repositories in NestJS

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

In this link https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/custom-repository i read that i must use something like this:

```
      export const UserRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User).extend({
        findByName(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
            return this.createQueryBuilder("user")
                .where("user.firstName = :firstName", { firstName })
                .andWhere("user.lastName = :lastName", { lastName })
                .getMany()
        },
    })
```

So i need do file user.repositories.ts , but i can`t understand how to get dataSource.getRepository()

```
import { DataSource} from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';

export const UserRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User).extend({})
```

Comment: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/data-source

Comment: Were you able to write a solution? I am in your same situation and I don't know how to manage the `dataSource` between modules

Answer (score 2):

just create a service and act it like a Repository.

```js
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Injectable()
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private userRepo: Repository<User>) {
    super(userRepo.target, userRepo.manager, userRepo.queryRunner)
  }

  findByUsername(username: string) {
    return this.userRepo.findOneBy({username})
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add this repo to your containing module. Also, you need to register the `User` entity in your containing module

```js
// your module
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature(User)],
  providers: [UserRepository]
})
```

Comment: However in this way you are losing all the default methods implemented in the repository and you have to import this and the repository when you have to deal with both. It smells a little

Comment: Yes only one important thing is missing: export class UserRepository  **extends Repository<User>** maybe @ali-shabani you can edit your code accordingly

Comment: The approach for creating the custom repository worked for me. However, there is a _silly mistake which might have been due to the later edits_ by @[Ali Shabani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8091444/ali-shabani).

In the constructor you need to call super() as UserRepository class is extending from Repository. 
`constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private userRepo: Repository<User>) { 
    super(userRepo.target, userRepo.manager, userRepo.queryRunner)
  }`

Comment: For the curious, this is basically exactly how `Repository.extend` is implemented within TypeORM. I think you can even safely just do `this.findOneBy` instead of calling the base repo directly (and thus you don't need to make it a member); there doesn't seem to be any difference.

https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/d4607a86723eef07e62e6d7321a07f3ae5ed1f90/src/repository/Repository.ts#L677-L693

Comment: One important thing worth noting though is that this approach doesn't work properly with transactions. 

https://typeorm.io/custom-repository#using-custom-repositories-in-transactions

Transactions have different execution contexts, and that won't work in this case when you're overriding the constructor like you are here.

I'm not sure if there's a proper solution that maintains all functionality.