# How to create custom (separate file) repository in NestJS 9 with TypeORM 0.3.x

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, repository-pattern

*This is not a duplicate Q. Please don't mark this as that.*

Following is not I want

```js
import { EntityRepository, Repository } from "typeorm";
import { Test } from "./test.model";
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

@EntityRepository(Test)
export class TestRepository extends Repository<Test> {}
```

the `@EntityRepository` decorator is now deprecated.

I also don't want to make a fake repository like in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/73352265/5420070

Don't want this either as I've to extract `manager` from `dataSource`, I don't want this because I think this is not the best way.

```js
    export const UserRepository = dataSource.getRepository(User).extend({
        //                        ^^^^^^^^^^ from where this came from
        findByName(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
            return this.createQueryBuilder("user")
                .where("user.firstName = :firstName", { firstName })
                .andWhere("user.lastName = :lastName", { lastName })
                .getMany()
        },
    })
```

Found above in: https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/custom-repository#how-to-create-custom-repository

I don't think this is in NestJS context.

What I want
Want to know right way to make custom repository in latest version of NestJS (v9) & TypeORM (v0.3). In `@EntityRepository` deprecation note, they said that need to extend the repo to create custom repo like `someRepo.extend({})`. I want to know how to do it in NestJS way

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, you could do something like the following.

This solution is inspired by the official [NestJS docs related to this topic](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#repository-pattern), with some customization.

## Steps to achieve it:

1. Create your *TypeOrm* entity as usual, let's say `UserEntity` (**user.entity.ts** file)
2. Create a `UserRepository` class (**user.repository.ts** file)
3. Create a `UserService` class as usual (**user.service.ts** file)
4. Import the `UserRepository` into your `UserService`
5. Update `UserModule` in order to provide the `UserRepository` and needed `UserEntity`

## Detailed implementation example

### 1. **user.entity.ts** file

```js
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity()
export class UserEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  firstName: string;

  @Column()
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ default: true })
  isActive: boolean;
}
```

### 2. **user.repository.ts** file

```js
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';

export class UserRepository extends Repository<UserEntity> {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UserEntity)
        private userRepository: Repository<UserEntity>
    ) {
        super(userRepository.target, userRepository.manager, userRepository.queryRunner);
    }

    // sample method for demo purposes
    async findByEmail(email: string): Promise<UserEntity> {
        return await this.userRepository.findOneBy({ email }); // could also be this.findOneBy({ email });, but depending on your IDE/TS settings, could warn that userRepository is not used though. Up to you to use either of the 2 methods
    }
    
    // your other custom methods in your repo...
}
```

### 3. & 4. **user.service.ts** file

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserRepository } from './user.repository';
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    private readonly userRepository: UserRepository, // import as usual
  ) {}

  findAll(): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
    return this.userRepository.find();
  }
  
  // call your repo method
  findOneByEmail(email: string): Promise<UserEntity> {
    return this.userRepository.findByEmail({ email });
  }

  findOne(id: number): Promise<UserEntity> {
    return this.userRepository.findOneBy({ id });
  }

  async remove(id: string): Promise<void> {
    await this.userRepository.delete(id);
  }
  
  // your other custom methods in your service...
}
```

### 5. Updating `UserModule` (**user.module.ts** file)

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';
import { UserEntity } from './user.entity';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([UserEntity])], // here we provide the TypeOrm support as usual, specifically for our UserEntity in this case
  providers: [UserService, UserRepository], // here we provide our custom repo
  controllers: [UserController],
  exports: [UserService, UserRepository] // add this only if you use service and/or custom repo within another module/service
})
export class UserModule {}
```

With this in place, you should be able to import the `UserModule` in your `AppModule` and be able to both implement custom methods in the `UserRepository` and use them in the `UserService`. You should also be able to call the `manager` and `queryRunnner` of the custom repository.

#### Additional Note

If you need to directly call your `UserRepository` methods from within another module/service, then update `UserModule` to export the `UserRepository`

Hope it helps, don't hesitate to comment.

Comment: I tried this solution and I get the error Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the CustomerRepository (?). Please make sure that the argument CustomerEntityRepository at index [0] is available in the CustomerModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is CustomerModule a valid NestJS module?
- If CustomerEntityRepository is a provider, is it part of the current CustomerModule?
- If CustomerEntityRepository is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within CustomerModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing CustomerEntityRepository */ ]
  })

Comment: Please provide more context to the comments, maybe a link to some repo in order to better understand your code :) Otherwise your error tells it all, you're missing something, somewhere =)

Comment: Pretty good solution for global repositories, but you cannot use this custom repository in a transaction. It would be nice to have an alternative for the old `entityManager.getCustomRepository(Foo)`.

Comment: Make sure *not* to use ```@InjectRepository(UserEntity)``` when you are creating the Repository class yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany } from "typeorm";
import { CustomBaseEntity } from "../core/custom-base.entity";//custom-made
@Entity({name: 'rcon_log', schema: 'dbo'})
export class LogEntity extends CustomBaseEntity{
------------your code-----------
}
```